# producing Avro encoding to Kafka

Tags: json, apache-kafka, avro

according to [AVRO reference documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/spec.html#Data+Serialization+and+Deserialization) there are 2 kinds of encoding: binary and JSON encoding,  but in most examples of avro messages Kafka producer scripts, it's never specified which encoding is used, I need an example of sending avro in binary encoding and another example of sending AVRO in JSON encoding to kafka, to conduct some tests, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> most examples of avro messages Kafka producer scripts, it's never specified which encoding is used

All examples I've seen use binary. Specifically, Confluent (or Apicurio, or AWS Glue) all use classes that use Avro API `BinaryEncoder` class. If you are wanting to use Avro, just use a Schema Registry; it'll be much easier than managing schemas on your own.

There's no reason to really use "Avro JSON Encoding" in Kafka. Binary dataformats are more compact and faster. But the [Avro documentation already shows how to create JSONEncoder class](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/io/EncoderFactory.html#jsonEncoder-org.apache.avro.Schema-java.io.OutputStream-) and pass it a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. There's nothing specific to Kafka beyond using `ByteArraySerializer` with the producer for that.

Answer (score 0):

The confluent avro library (io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer) does **not** provide an option for JSON encoding of Avro data. This was confusing to me as well, since Confluent's docs [mention](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#test-drive-avro-schema) the option for JSON encoding. However their library explicitly makes use of binary Avro encoding with no option to configure to use the json encodings:

- `AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer`

  - Contains an instance of `org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory`

    - Uses `encoderFactory.directBinaryEncoder(out, null)` to encode data.
- `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer`

  - Contains an instance of `org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory`

    - Uses `decoderFactory.binaryDecoder(buffer)` to decode data.

I can't speak to why this may be other than the fact that binary encoded data is much more compact... It seems if you want to use JSON encoded Avro the producer and all consumers will need to use a different library to write and read the Kafka topic.  I don't have an open source library option to offer, you may need to roll your own.

If it isn't realistic within your organization to expect all Kafka consumers (and producers) that interact with your topic to **not** use the confluent library, then you'll want to stick to binary encoded Avro.

Comment: To clarify the docs, it's talking about the kafka-avro-console producer/consumer scripts, but the data on the broker will still be binary Avro, yes